# Action and Status Codes - Decode

Tags: sabre

Is there a resource somewhere that defines the meanings of the various action and status codes used in Sabre PNRs? E.g., for segment, seats, SSRs, AncillaryServices, fares, tickets, etc.

I've looked on the Sabre developer site but can't find anything there.

Answer (score 0):

- [List from TP docs](https://support.travelport.com/webhelp/uapi/Content/Air/Shared_Air_Topics/Air_Status_Codes.htm)
- [Sabre Action codes description](https://central.sabre.com/s/article/action-codes)
- [Sabre Status codes description](https://central.sabre.com/s/article/status-codes---overview)